# como leer un diccionario de un txt en python

Tags: python, diccionarios, txt

Tengo un Txt

```py
    "{'03/01/20': ['luiana','macarena']}\n"
    "{'03/01/21': ['juana','roberta','mariana'}\n"
    "{'03/01/24': ['pedro','jose','mario','luis']}\n"
    "{'03/01/22': ['emanuel']}\n"
```

Lo quiero leer como diccionario, pero no sé como hacerlo. (en python) 
intento con:

```py
    f = open ('usuarios.txt','r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    whip=eval(str(lines))
```

pero no funciona...

Mi idea es intentar leer solo los diccionarios donde su valor sea 03/01/24

Answer (score 0):

He añadido código para crear el fichero. Tenia que añadir un ']' en la segunda línea.

```
contenido = ( "{'03/01/20': ['luiana','macarena']}\n"
              "{'03/01/21': ['juana','roberta','mariana']}\n"
              "{'03/01/24': ['pedro','jose','mario','luis']}\n"
              "{'03/01/22': ['emanuel']}\n" )
with open("mi_dict.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(contenido)
```

Para leerlo:

```
mi_dict = {}
with open("mi_dict.txt", "r") as fp:
    for linea in fp.readlines():
        mi_dict.update(eval(linea))
print(mi_dict)
```

Comment: ¿Ha sido útil la respuesta?